# Continue installation even after download failure with Inno Download Plugin

Tags: inno-setup, setup-project, inno-download-plugin

On some of the systems (mostly Windows 7), we are getting `Download failed: An error occurred in the secure channel support` error while downloading files using Inno Download Plugin. We tried adding `idpSetOption('AllowContinue', '1');` found from one of the answers but that did not solve the issue. The files we are downloading are not super critical, so we can ignore error if downloading fails and setup should continue.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

```
#include "D:\idp.iss"

[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin
AppName=My Project
AppVersion=2.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Project
DefaultGroupName=My Project
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\My Project.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=D:\setup
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=Setup

[Files]
Source: "My Project.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

Source: "{tmp}\online.exe"; DestDir: "{commondesktop}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 1736547
Source: "{tmp}\offline.exe"; DestDir: "{commondesktop}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 166148

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Project"; Filename: "{app}\My Project.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Comment: "Launch My Project"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\My Project.EXE"; Description: "My Project"; Flags: postinstall

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpSetOption('AllowContinue', '1');
    idpAddFileSize('https://download.mysite.com/download/online.exe', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\online.exe'), 1736547);
    idpAddFileSize('https://download.mysite.com/download/offline.exe', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\offline.exe'), 166148);

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Comment: Can you also post a log file showing the failure?

Comment: I did not know that Inno Setup creates log file. I now searched and found that it is stored in temp directory. I will grab log once I have another instance of failure on customer computer. Thanks for sharing knowledge!

Comment: It does not create log file on its own. Only if you tell it to by `/log` command-line switch.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl There the SetupLogging approach: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_setuplogging.htm